# Не работает A[i][j]=value и происходит вылет программы. Почему?

Tags: c++, классы, матрицы, unique-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;
using std::cout;

typedef unsigned int uint;

class CMatrix;

class Line
{
    unique_ptr<CMatrix> owner;
    uint row;
public:
/*Constructor*/
    Line(CMatrix& Matrix, uint i) : owner(&Matrix), row(i) { ; }
/*Operator overload*/
    double operator[](uint column);
};

class CMatrix
{
    uint m;
    uint n;
    double x;
public:
    unique_ptr<unique_ptr<double[]>[]> ptrMatrix2D;
/*Constructor*/
    CMatrix(uint rows, uint columns) :
        m(rows),
        n(columns),
        x(0.0),
        ptrMatrix2D(make_unique<unique_ptr<double[]>[]>(m)) // создание m указателей
    {

        for (uint i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            ptrMatrix2D[i] = make_unique<double[]>(n); // создание n элементов
            for (uint j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                ptrMatrix2D[i][j] = x;
                cout << ptrMatrix2D[i][j] << "\t";
                x++;
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
/*Method*/
    double cell(uint row, uint column) { return ptrMatrix2D[row][column]; }
/*Operator overload*/
    Line operator[](uint row) { return Line(*this, row); }
};

/*Description operator overload class Line*/
double Line::operator[](uint column) { return owner->cell(row, column); }

int main() {

    CMatrix A(5, 5);
    cout << "Test Matrix: " << A[0][4] << "\n";
    //A[0][4] = 2 * A[0][4];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда выполнилась строка `cout << "Test Matrix: " << A[0][4] << "\n";`, промежуточные объекты удаляются. В том числе удаляются возвращаемые объекты методов `operator[]`.

Взглянем сюда:

```
Line operator[](uint row) { return Line(*this, row); }
```

Здесь передается `this` в `Line`. И этот `Line` возвращается.

Теперь взглянем на объявление `Line`:

```
class Line
{
    unique_ptr<CMatrix> owner; // <<< Указатель, который сам очищается

    // ...
};
```

Что произойдет с ним при удалении `Line`? Правильно, он тоже попытается подчиститься. А что же вы в него положили? Адрес объекта `CMatrix`:

```
int main() {

    CMatrix A(5, 5);  // <<< Объвялено в стеке
    cout << "Test Matrix: " << A[0][4] << "\n";
}
```

Это примерно тоже, что и:

```
int main() {

    CMatrix A(5, 5);  // <<< Объвялено в стеке
    delete &A;
}
```

Проще говоря, так делать нельзя. И вообще, было б неплохо изменить отношения между классами. У вас получается, что они слишком много знают друг о друге.

Comment: спасибо! Получается, что на текущий объект `A` стоит уник поинтер `ptrMatrix2D`, а оригинал самого объекта `A` передаётся уник поинтеру `owner` и получается, что один уник поинтер передается другому через объект, но один уник поинтер нельзя передать другому уник поинтеру, на то он и уникальный. Вот ошибка и вылетает, т.е. вылетать будет всегда на запись `A[i][j]`. Можно поправить через "утечку" памяти `CMatrix* owner;`, но мне такой вариант не очень нравится.

Comment: Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь покажет грамотное отношение между объектами при "перегрузке оператора `[ ][ ]`" на уник поинтерах.

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае у вас возвращается в `A[][]`

```
double operator[](uint column);
```

просто `double`. Так что ваше присваивание выглядит как присваивание значению, то есть как

```
5.678 = 8.91011;
```

Но так это не работает. Просто `double` не может быьт lvalue.

Как минимум нужно возвращать ссылку `double&`. Это кроме того, что вам написал @Bogdan.

Comment: Каюсь, поправил: `double& operator[](uint column);`, `double& cell(uint row, uint column) { return ptrMatrix2D[row][column]; }` и `double& Line::operator[](uint column) { return owner->cell(row, column); }` и всё работает.